# Debugging spring boot in VS code problem: ClassNotFoundException: javax/smartcardio/CardPermission

Tags: spring, spring-boot, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

When attempting to debug my Java code in Visual Studio Code, I encounter the following error: "Exception has occurred: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax/smartcardio/CardPermission". Despite extensive searching, I haven't found any relevant solutions online. It's worth noting that this class doesn't appear to be a direct dependency of my project, but rather part of the JDK installation pack.

My application runs smoothly and functions as expected, and I'm certain that neither CardPermission nor smartcardio are utilized in my codebase.

To address the issue, I've attempted to manually include the java.smartcardio module in my Maven build by modifying the pom.xml as follows:

```
<jvmArguments>--add-modules java.smartcardio</jvmArguments>
<configuration>
        <argLine>--add-modules java.smartcardio</argLine>
</configuration>
```

After changing the pom and reinstalling the JDK and trying remote debugging, reinstalling redhat nothing seemed to work, I tried to change settings.json to skip it, it did not help, if I try to go over it I get the next error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null KeyStore name.
can please anybody help me where to look as I do not see that anyone has the same issue. I am not using spring security